# Trying to use Base MVC/Page and Model in the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a base class that I'm trying to use in a View. I understand now that @model is really an implementation of 'WebViewPage'. So, I believe there is probably a better way to accomplish what I want, maybe with an Action Filter or my BaseController object.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
public abstract class AuthenticatedViewPageBase : WebViewPage
{
    private Login _user;

    protected override void InitializePage()
    {
        _user = Session["User"] as Login;
    }

    public bool HasPermission(Permissions permission)
    {
        return HasPermission(new List<Permissions> { permission });
    }
    public bool HasPermission(List<Permissions> permissions)
    {
        if (_user == null)
            _user = Session["User"] as Login;

        return _user != null && permissions.Any(thisPerm => _user.Permissions.Any(p => p.PermissionId == (int)thisPerm));
    }
}
```

And use it in a List View like this:

```
@using PublicationSystem.Model.Enums
@inherits PublicationSystem.Helpers.AuthenticatedViewPageBase
@model IEnumerable<PublicationSystem.Model.Profile>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSmBanner.cshtml";
}

@if (HasPermission(new List<Permissions>
{
    Permissions.userCreate
}))
{
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create");
    </p>
}
....
```

But of course, I cannot use @inherits and @model together. (The Profile class is a simple model.)

What would be a good way to get abilities of function like HasPermission in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I defined two similar classes:

```
public abstract class AuthenticatedViewPageBase : WebViewPage
{
    //....
}

public abstract class AuthenticatedViewPageBase<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    //....
}
```

Then set \Views\web.config like this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="PublicationSystem.Helpers.AuthenticatedViewPageBase">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      <add namespace="PublicationSystem" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Now my pages can use @model as normally and get the custom methods from my abstract version of WebViewPage.

```
@model IEnumerable<PublicationSystem.Model.Profile>
```